# javascript date itialising date produces erroneous date

Tags: javascript, date

Why does

```
new Date(2016, 3, 30);
```

produce:

```
Sat Apr 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

should it not be Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)

Comment: Months are zero (0 = Jan) based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because

```
new Date(2016, 3, 30);
```

means

**year**: 2016

**month**: 3 - 0: jan, 1: feb, 2:mar, 3: april

**day**: 30

Just do this:

```
 new Date(2016, 2, 30);
```

Comment: Who ever heard of month zero.  lol.  javascript has some odd ways.

Comment: @John—javascript's Date was modelled on Java's Date. Indexing from zero is actually quite handy. ;-)